# how to show percentage of progress bar in inertia with nprogress?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, progress-bar, inertiajs

I'm working on laravel project and using vuejs with inertia as a frontend. i made a simple progress bar with inertia when the user uploads a file to show the progress of uploading file.

```
onStart : () => {
      Inertia.on('progress', (event) => {
         if (event.detail.progress.percentage) {
            NProgress.set((event.detail.progress.percentage / 100) * 0.98);
        }
      });
},
```

it working fine but i also want to show the percentage on the progress bar. how to do this.

**for more info on progress indicators in inertia.**

https://inertiajs.com/progress-indicators